# Can the word "paired" be used when describing more than two objects?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence acceptable?

> Matches are played three v. three. In the first hundred matches, teams are randomly paired.

Can "paired" be used in this case, since it is 3 teams that are being put together?

**EDIT:**
There seems to be a little confusion on what I'm trying to describe here. The game is a robotics competition (FIRST Robotics Competition). Teams of up to 50 people each build a robot and bring it to a competition. The matches are played 3 robots vs. 3 robots. In the first hundred matches, the 3 robots on each alliance are randomly paired.

Comment: You misunderstood. The teams are being paired, not the players on each team. Pair is only ever for two things.

Comment: @Mitch Right, that is what I meant. The word "pair" refers to 2 objects, no? So can it  be used when we are talking about three teams?

Comment: No, pair cannot be used for a (strange) game where 3 teams play together. What you're supposed to understand from the two sentences is "Matches (between two teams) are played three (players) v. three (players). In the first hundred matches, teams are randomly paired."

Comment: Why not remove the difficult contextualising here? Three-team football matches seem to have not really caught on (I believe they were trialled in Ireland). I'd suggest 'Can we say "A suspect card, a room card  and a weapon card are hidden without looking at them in the envelope. There are, of course, many possible pairings."?' And the answer is 'No'.

Comment: @Mitch please see my post update.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth please see my post update

Comment: No' you can't use 'paired'. Use 'grouped'.

Comment: That *The game is a robotics competition* makes what difference, as opposed to a tug-o-war or a football game, please?
Teams of *up to 50 people* helps explain this how?
If matches are played 3 vs 3 then clearly no robots or teams are in any way *paired*.
Whether anything about an *alliance* is relevant depends on what an *alliance* means here.
*Matched/grouped/opposed* or something like that, perhaps…

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

"Matches are paired three against three, the teams being randomly picked in the first one hundred matches."

The problem was the order in which you were stating them. Try swapping "three v three" "First hundred matches" and "teams are randomly paired" around until it flows right