# Can a pairing exist of more than two items?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Can a *pairing* exist with more than two items?

> His favorite meal is a pairing of tofu, bok choy, and straw mushrooms.

If not, what word should be used to represent a 'pairing' of three items?

Comment: Maybe "*combination*"?  A pairing is matching two items that work well together:  a wine is paired with a steak.  Your example sounds more like a recipe for a dish that combines those ingredients.

Comment: "Tofu, bok choy" is a dish. That should clear the picture for you.

Comment: @Jim The question is about whether we can use *pairing* -- suggestions of alternatives makes it "writing advice" (OT).

Comment: @Kris - The implication of my comment is that it is *not* acceptable to use pairing and the suggestions are in response to the "*If not, what word should be used...*"  It could be considered a SWR as well.

Comment: @Jim Note the Oxford comma!

Comment: @Kris- What about it?

Comment: @Kris - Oh, are you saying that the "Tofu, Bok choy dish is being paired with straw mushrooms?  I would think that would only be valid if the comma *wasn't* there.

Comment: Asked (and closed) before at [Can the word 'paired' be used when describing more than two objects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414246/can-the-word-paired-be-used-when-describing-more-than-two-objects).

Comment: @Kris “Tofu, bok choy” is **not** a dish. I have no idea what you think either of your enigmatic and singularly unhelpful comments were supposed to make clear, but they didn’t.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Google it. Good Luck!

Comment: @Kris That’s yet another unhelpful, passive-aggressive comment which does nothing to clarify the question or further any discussion on it. Please refrain from derailing questions with such comments.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Can a pair be used for 3 items? No; it always means 2 of something.
What word should be used to represent a 'pairing'of 3 items ? trio.